# How to avoid iBeacon false positives on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon

I've got a class that implementing `CLLocationManagerDelegate` and monitors a beacon region. It receives `didEnterRegion` and `didExitRegion` events, amongst other things.

Sometimes I get rapid switching between region entered and left states, even though I'm sat next to the beacon within 1m. The beacon advertising frequency is set to 500ms and TX power is set to -79 and the RSSI is around -55 when measured within 1m range.

The entry/exit switching looks like this on a timeline

```
...
12:01 - didEnterRegion
12:02 - didExitRegion
12:05 - didEnterRegion
...
```

AFAIK iOS should wait 30 seconds before confirming an exit in order to avoid false, but this isn't happening.

Do you have any tips for solve this problem? Or if there's a library to do it for me?

**Potential Solution?**

Note: My initial solution idea is to write a class that buffers region entry/exit events for 10 seconds and then detects these false positives and removes them from the event stream. It would republish the event without the fluxuations. E.g. for the previous example on one event would be published.

`12:05 - didEnterRegion`

If you like this approach, any ideas for a simple implementation in Swift?

Comment: You say the power is -79 dBm.  Do you mean this is the RSSI level you are at 1m?  Test this by using the Locate app to measure the rssi at 1m away.    https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-beacon/id738709014?mt=8    What does it say?  I suspect you really are getting 30s or more with no detections.  You need to solve this before doing anything else.

Comment: Really appreciate the input. RSSI is about -55 at under 1m range. The -79 was the TX power setting, would that be in dBm units?

Comment: Really appreciate the input. 

Calibration in Locate Beacon shows 1-Meter Tx Power value at -62 at 1m range.  

The -79 was the TX power setting I programmed on the beacon, would that be in dBm units? I guess I could update this to -62 to optimise for 1m range

How do I use the Locate Beacon app to show detections? 

That sounds like a good idea to see how often the app is getting an advertisement.

Comment: The RSSI of -62 at one meter is plenty strong.  Calibration to correct the txPower will help improve distance estimates but will not affect region entry/exits, so I believe is is a red herring.  You cannot use Locate to count packet detections as Apple has no API to do this.  You could do so with an Android device if you have one.  https://github.com/davidgyoung/ble-advert-counter